# Is there a way to automatically display the file path on every print whether its Word, Excel, PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, printing, path

I am working with one of our help desk tickets and I personally don't think it's possible unless you go through some crazy scripting... The help desk ticket client was asking if is there a way to automatically display the file path of a file on every print... I know there's a way to do it for a single document for word and excel. But he wants to know if he can do it for all of the programs... Seems a bit unrealistic but you never know. Thanks guys!

BTW he's using an HP P4015 printer

Comment: Only the application can know what file it is working on, so it would be necessary to adopt custom headers within each separate application. The print system knows the user who invoked a print job, as well as other data, such as the time and date of the job, but there is no information about the source file unless the application generates it.

Answer (score 1):

For existing Office documents that aren't started by a (modified) Normal template, it would be simple enough to record a macro of you doing it on one document, and add a button for that to the Quick Access Toolbar.  Make it with a printer icon, and end your script with the Print dialog - your user will click the button to print, and it will just have the path and filename right where you need it!

Recording a macro is tricky business, but totally doable.  Just work slowly and carefully while recording, but you'll probably need to edit the vb code.  Tons of resources and examples out there, just google "Word VBA "

Outside of Office, you're sol unless you can write printer drivers and add-ins for the programs you're printing from

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not the OP but this is exactly what I was looking for, for Excel specifically.  Every other suggestion out there involves the normal template, which will only affect new documents going forward.  I've now got a macro button that adds a footer and then brings up the print dialog!

Answer (score 0):

I have partial solution to this, at least the Excel part.

1. Since you know how to do it for a single document do it just once, do ALL of the formatting.
2. Save as "Excel template" and choose folder `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` where instead of "User" you enter the actual user name

Once you do that ALL of newly created sheets by this user will look like the sheet that you just saved, with proper footer etc..

- I never tried this on Word but I believe that this will work on Word as well
- I am using Excel 2010, on Windows 7 if you are using something else you might need to save the template somewhere else
- You have to save that file in all of users' folders so that they all can take advantage of this, but hey its just a setup results will last forever

I hope this helps